# objective C switching from a view to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to the objective C programming and I am in a position where I need to create an iPhone App really quickly. 
I am using XCode 4.2

I have a problem transferring an NSString variable from one view to the other .
the two views are in two different sets of .h and .m classes

in the first class in the .h i have something like this

```
@interface firstview : UIViewController {
NSString *test;
}

-(IBAction)testbutton
@end
```

in the .m of the firstview I have

```
-(IBAction)testbutton{
secondView *second; 
[second setText:text]; //set text is a function that will take an NSString parameter
second= [[secondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

in the .h of the secondView I wrote

```
@interface secondView : UIViewController{
-IB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but you're trying to call `-setText:` before `second` points to a valid object! Do this instead:

```
-(IBAction)testbutton{
    secondView *second; 
    second = [[secondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [second setText:text]; //set text is a function that will take an NSString parameter
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

Also, the interface you give for your `secondView` class looks both incorrect and incomplete -- I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `-IB` part. And it'd help in the future if you follow the usual Objective-C naming convention and start class names with an uppercase character: `SecondView` instead of `secondView`. Finally, I'd advise against naming a view controller ending in "...View", since that makes it easy to confuse the view controller with a UIView. All together, it should look something like this:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *text;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@end
```

Declaring `text` as an instance variable is optional there -- if you don't do it, the compiler will create an ivar if you synthesize the accessors for your `text` property.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
-(IBAction)testbutton{
    secondView *second; 
    second = [[secondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [second setText:text]; //set text is a function that will take an NSString parameter
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

In your original version, you were initializing (i.e. instantiating) your second view *after* calling `setText:` on it. You need to initialize it and *then* set the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text after you allocate and initialize.

```
-(IBAction) testButton {
    secondView *second = [[[secondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [second setText:text];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```